# React.js hooks Weird Behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason the default value always shows up and the last value entered on the inputs does not.

***APP.JS***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import User from './Components/User';
import Card from './Components/Card';

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState([{username: "Alex", age: 11}]);

  const handleUserAdd = (user1) => {
      setUser(prevState => ([
        ...prevState, user1
      ]));

    console.log(user);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card>
         <User onUserAdd={handleUserAdd}/>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***USER.JS***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const User = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [years, setYears] = useState(0);
    const handleOnNameChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleOnAgeChange = (e) => {
        setYears(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleOnSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        //if(years !== 0){
            const user = {
                username: name,
                age: years
            };
            props.onUserAdd(user);
        //}
        setName("");
        setYears(0);
    }
    return ( 
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Username:</label>
                    <input className="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={name} onChange={handleOnNameChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Age:</label>
                    <input type="number" min={1} max={120} className="form-control" value={years} onChange={handleOnAgeChange} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default User;
```

***What is showing up:***
[image]

It shows Alex 11, which is the default value, if i put it on empty it will show it as an empty item.
On the inputs, i entered 3 values: Value 1, 1; Value 2,2; Value 3,3. Value 3,3 is not showing up, if i eneter Value4,4 then Value 3 will show up and Value 4,4 will not. I do not understand why it's filling the first value with the default one instead of changing it to Value1,1. And why is it not showing the last one?

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: The user state is not being given to the User component? Also `console.log(user);` inside `handleUserAdd` will show the old value.

Comment: Don't `console.log(user)` right after u `setUser` because setting state is async. Put `console.log(user)` outside  `handleUserAdd` function and you can see the correct value on next render.

Comment: And use `parseInt()` to convert the age string to number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)